# React: Not same value in program when i change the state of my variable with post-increment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

When i change the variable state with the post-increment operator, the `count` variable use the old value...
Let me explain with this app exemple:

When i press the button with the following code, the app shows me this series:

```
0 - 0 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 4 - 5 - 5 ...
```

But in the mathematic logic, it should shows this series:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 ...
```

The code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Button, SafeAreaView, Text, View, } from 'react-native';

function App(){
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Text>{count}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={()=>{
            console.log("A",count); // <--- OLD value: 0
            setCount(count++);      // <--- NEW value: so, it setState count to 0.
            console.log("Z",count); // <--- NEW value: 1
            /*
                So, know, in my app count has 0. But the program has 1. Ok.
                But, if i press again, setState will not use the new value
                who is 1, but the old value who is 0! Why !?
            */
          }}
          title="Press!"
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setCount(count++);
```

this doesn't increment the state until another render.

Change it to:

```
setCount(count + 1)
```

What `setCount(count++)` does is increment the variable, which doesn't tie into the lifecycle methods of the component because you didn't use the setter.

So, what you're doing is

- 0 - render the default value
- 0 - setCount(count++) doesn't update
  state, just the count variable so render 0 again
- 1 - you've now
  setCount to the count variable, which is now 1 from last render
- 1 - you've rendered current state, which is still 1 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

When you use a setState the component rerender.

That means that the component with state 0 is destroyed, and a new component with state 1, is show brand new.

When you call a console log inmediatly after a setState, or it wont be shown in console   or, in your case it shows the value of the component before being destroyed.

To use wisely a console log on a state, apply the console log before the return of the react component

```
function App(){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log(count)
  return ( ...
)}
```